Android Beam alternative for sending text messages
I am currently developing an Android app where I need to transfer a URL between 2 devices. I have implemented this with creating and scanning a QR code. I wanted to do this also through NFC - the phones would get near each other and the URL would be exchanged between them. However, it seems that Android Beam (which, if I understand correctly was the correct way of doing this) is deprecated and no longer available. I've seen that Nearby Connections is the new recommended way of transferring data between 2 phones, but it seems to me like an overkill and also more error-prone compared to NFC (e.g. handling situations with multiple phones with the app opened and requesting to connect).
Can I use NFC to do this even without Android Beam? If not, is there any viable alternative (can also be Nearby Connections, I might be wrong about its shortcomings in this usecase)?

Yes you can still send data with NFC, it's just a bit more complicated.
You can do it by one Android phone using Host Card Emulation (HCE) to emulate a NFC Tag and then the other reads it like a normal Type 4A NFC Tag.
An example that sends a NDef Text Record between phones is at https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid
This can easily be change to send a NDef URL Record instead.
